# Move Grub to a different drive

Tags: linux, debian, grub, grub2, crunchbang

I recently added a new ssd to my machine which I intended to have as my main drive. I installed crunchbang and everything went fine, except I unthinkingly accepted updating/overwriting the MBR on my original drive.

What I want to do now is add grub/MBR to my new ssd so I can boot off that without having to go through the MBR on the other drive. Is there a way of installing grub on this new drive? Preferably without booting into a live cd (nouveau issues).

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [grub-install](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html) program, with name of the ssd disk like: /dev/sdb.
To find out what name your disk has, try `fdisk -l`.