# Grub File Stolen ( Windows and openSUSE )

Tags: windows, linux, grub

I have a problem with my computer. I installed openSUSE on my external, and I still have Windows on my HDD. OpenSus took the Grub file and placed it on my external, so now I have to open OpenSus to open Windows.

I never got a Windows CD when I bought my computer. I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my external, but then I will have to format my external in which case I will lose the Grub file causing me to lose Windows, which I can't afford to do... yet. Does anyone have an idea what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/380766/move-grub-to-a-different-drive) features a similar question without going into much detail or instructions.

[This website](http://www.mentby.com/Group/opensuse/moving-grubboot-to-second-disk.html) has much more in depth instructions involving changing bootable boot volumes around.

[This](http://blog.nikolaidis.com/2008/06/28/moving-grub-from-the-mbr-to-the-install-partition/) looks like much easier instructions. Also [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/bootinfoscript/index.php?title=Boot_Problems:Computer_does_not_boot_without_external_drive) features what to do if you have Grub spread across drives.

Hope one/all of those help!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, backing up the whole drive - clonezilla or macrium reflect is a good option (I prefer macrium here, for various reasons) before you do anyting

Boot into windows and install [easybcd](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) - use that to install the windows bootloader into the MBR, and chainload suse if necessary with the linux loading option from there.

Test run the new boot order and see if everything works as desired.

If it works, well, you can do as you like with the external drive.

Else use the  recovery disk to restore the old install (macrium is nice here since you can choose to install the windows bootloader again)